# How do I scale vertices evenly among a selection?

Tags: transforms, extrude

This seems like a broad question so I will put in a picture showing you what I am intending to do.[image: Example Picture]

I have a very basic house structure, and I would like to extrude/scale it inward, evenly across all sides. However, you will notice that the two sides near the center are scaling at much smaller proportions, and I am looking for evenly distributed scaling across all vertices.

The reasoning behind me wanting to do this is to add an evenly proportioned brick-sized inset around the home for detail purposes. I am aware of the loop cut, however I am under the impression that extrude/scale is considered the fastest way of accomplishing this based on watching speed builders on Youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. As it turns out, I was using the wrong tool for the job. The proper way to scale something evenly across all sides is to use **"Shrink/Fatten"** by pressing **Alt+S**. Once I begin shrinking or fattening my object, I only need to press **S** to make all the edges even, and I can adjust it to my liking.